# Maven shader plugin doesn't shade dependencies in artifact

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, maven-plugin

Okay I have played around with some more dependencies and it seems that every dependency I have isn't getting shaded into my jar file. why is that happening?

I have created different projects with different group and artifact ids but every project I make keeps having the same issue.

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.paper</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WeirdPlugin</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.paper.test.Main
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.paper.test.Main
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.paper.test.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>destroystokyo-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.destroystokyo.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.lucko.luckperms</groupId>
            <artifactId>luckperms-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

TestPlugin.iml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="minecraft" name="Minecraft">
      <configuration>
        <autoDetectTypes>
          <platformType>PAPER</platformType>
        </autoDetectTypes>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: com.destroystokyo.paper:paper-api:1.14.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: junit:junit:4.10" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: com.google.guava:guava:21.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: net.md-5:bungeecord-chat:1.13-SNAPSHOT" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.23" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.ow2.asm:asm:7.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:1.4.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:1.4.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:noaop:2.1.7" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="RUNTIME" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:1.7" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:1.7" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:1.7" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:1.7" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:2.2.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:1.5.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:1.4" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:3.1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-transfer:0.10.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:3.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:3.1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:3.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:0.9.0.M2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: commons-io:commons-io:2.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.vafer:jdependency:2.1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0-beta" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.11.11" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.11.11" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jooq:jooq:3.11.11" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: me.lucko.luckperms:luckperms-api:4.4" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for everything I want to do that depends on one of the dependencies.
I have tried many things edited pom.xml and TestPlugin.iml in many ways still nothing only the things that depends on bukkit/paper dependency works absolutely fine I am clueless at this point.

Used mvn clean install and mvn dependency:tree and it works well but when I put it in the server's plugins it's just goes broken.

Followed this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) and changed everything I had to changed same result.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. It seems that this is related to how the `maven-shade-plugin` cooperates with creating a plugin. I'm not sure how this works, but I'd look for the problem there. The reason why code generation might have worked in IntelliJ is because you duplicated the configuration. You're also using the `jooq-codegen-maven` plugin, which seems redundant with your programmatic code generator configuration.

Comment: I did use the code generator through maven until I found the programmatic code generator.

Comment: Also is the problem caused by how I set it up or something else that I might did wrong?

Comment: I don't know. I told you what I suspect, but you'll have to verify on your end.

Comment: Changed the configuration and instead of making a method for it put it in the onEnable and deleted the maven code-gen plugin still same issue.

Comment: Mordechai, you're not really investigating what I've suggested, are you :) The problem is (probably) that the jOOQ-codegen dependency doesn't correctly get shaded into your plugin. I would search for all build/classpath related issues. This has nothing to do with your particular code.

Comment: Alright I see just wanted to check, also thank you for your time Lukas.

Comment: I have ran ```mvn dependency:tree``` and it shows the jooq-code dependency in the shaded jar dependencies list, I have also ran jdeps on my jar it lists meta.jaxb and codegen but says "not found"

Comment: Okay I'll change this thread entirely because its a different problem and not exactly jOOQ related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually fixed it with this code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.DGD</groupId>
    <artifactId>PapaPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PapaPlugin</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>destroystokyo-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.destroystokyo.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.lucko.luckperms</groupId>
            <artifactId>luckperms-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.3_464</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opus-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```